# How can one bypass the need to calculate eigenmatrix of a matrix to calculate its determinant?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a way to calculate determinant of eigenmatrix of a matrix w/o calculating eigenmatrix? By eigenmatrix, I mean a diagonal matrix with elements of diagonal being coordinates of eigenvector of said matrix.

While discussing this with someone, I was told "determinants are invariant under similarity". What does that mean?

Comment: Your question title and question details don't match.

Comment: Once you write down that a matrix $A $ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D $,  it should be clear that $A $ and $D $ have equal determinants.

Comment: How to compute the determinant is discussed in the [Wikiepedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) to some extend. If you want to know a specifically clever approach for a certain matrix or matrix type, you have to give more information.

Comment: @hardmath what does "similar" mean here? What does it mean for matrices to be similar? Also, how do you know that a matrix and it's eigenmatrix are similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant of the matrix is the product of the eigenvalues of that matrix.

If $A $ is diagonisable by some diagonal $D $, ie $A=PDP^{-1} $, then by properties of the determinant $det (A)=det (D)$, taking the determinant of both sides of the equation.

This obviously works if instead of $D $ we have another matrix that is similar to $A $: $A=PBP^{-1} $ implies $det (A)=det (B)$, and the determinant of $A $ is invarient, ie $det (A)=det (D)=det (B)$.

Comment: First of all thanks, but what does "diagonisable" for a matrix mean? Yes, i see u have given a mathematical description but it's there a an intuitive explanation for it.

Comment: In simple terms, it means it is similar to a diagonal matric, ie the algebraic identity $A=PDP^{-1}$ holds. If we look at $A $ as representing a geometric/linear transformation, this means that with respect to the basis of its eigenvectors, $A $ has diagonal form (scaling along the eigenvectors).